# How to role work for diffrent users login?

Tags: php, symfony

- login.php for login page username or password

  ```
  $username=$_POST['username'];
  $password=$_POST['password'];

  $query="select * from login_table where username="'.$useranem .'"and password'".$password.'";
  $data=   mysql_query($query);
  ```
- successfully data true return .
- now id pass into role_table .
- now to how to define role .

Comment: do not use mysql functions as it is not supported. switch to PDO or mysqli. ALso used prepared statements. Do not store passwords as they are. use either password_hash or some encryption.. Also why the Symfony2 tag??

Comment: Did you tried [Authentication component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/security/authentication.html)? Also you can read  [this tutorial](http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login_setup.html) about login form.

Answer (score 1):

- first get id then pass into role_table
- next if condition role different dashboard open according to role

Suppose you have roleuser

```
$roleuser= 'admin';
$roleuser='user';

if($roleuser=='admin')
{
redirect('/admin');
}elseif($roleuser=='user')
{
redirect('/user');
}
```